# Javascript minification with semicolon insertion

Tags: javascript, minify

Is there any Javascript minifier/compressor which will insert semicolons as necessary (or, one which works with source code which doesn't use semicolons)? I've started using a library which is really great, but the developer considers the semicolons as "unnecessary clutter"...

Comment: So show the results of your current minifier to the developer and asks him if he still sees semicolons as "unnecessary". ;-)

Comment: You should tell the developer to plug "javascript semicolon insertion gotcha" into their favourite search engine and to then read some of the articles returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I was in a similar situation a couple of years ago, I seem to recall that the solution was essentially "the more the merrier"!

Firstly I ran the script through [Dojo Shrinksafe](http://o.dojotoolkit.org/docs/shrinksafe) on very modest compression settings.  Because it uses Rhino, it would actually interpret the JS and then write out an equivalent version with syntactically correct semicolons.

From there, I fed the output into [Dean Edward's /packer/](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/), which (at the time, at least) was the highest-compression library that produced consistently functional output.  This library requires the input to have semicolons, but that wasn't a problem thanks to the output from ShrinkSafe.

(Note that this is from memory and I haven't tested it recently, but there's no reason why the principle shouldn't hold any more.  If ShrinkSafe doesn't insert semicolons for you, perhaps there's some other JS-preprocessing tool that will automatically do this?  Modulo, of course, the fact that semicolon insertion is not 100% deterministic).

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! For any others wanting to run this locally, the download links on the Dojo site are broken. Shrinksafe is one of the packaged tools in the Toolkit available here: http://dojotoolkit.org/download -- or the SVN repo is here: http://svn.dojotoolkit.org/src/util/trunk/shrinksafe/

Comment: @nickf: Thanks, the documentation link is also broken; a newer version (the current one?) can be found at http://o.dojotoolkit.org/docs/shrinksafe

Comment: Thanks guys, I've updated the link to the one that Marcel provided.

Comment: I actually found the original link to still be very useful, since it provides an online tool. It let me see that it worked before I invested any time in getting it working locally.